# linq query getting Unable to cast object of type 'System.Boolean' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, linq

My problem is in the Where clause `table1.Field<string>(3) == table2.Field<string>(3)`. These values are either a 0 or 1, which i think linq changes it to a bool value. Linq gets "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Boolean' to type 'System.String'".

I tried `table1[3].ToString() == table2[3].ToString()`, but it comes up with no errors or matching rows, which I know it should come up with some.

My query:

```
var match = (from table1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                     join table2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on table1[1].ToString() equals table2[1].ToString())
                     where table1.Field<string>(3) == table2.Field<string>(3)
                     && table1.Field<string>("ID") == table2.Field<string>("ID")
                     select table1).ToList();
```

I'm looking to add more where clauses on the row, but it fails on the ones that have a 0 or 1 value to compare.

Thanks for the help

Comment: If you remove that condition, do you have records in your result?

Comment: have you tried `String.Equal()` method?

Comment: @Hackerman Yes. I can even add other Where clause that don't have a value of 0 or 1 and it works

Comment: @Media Yes, same issues

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like the root problem is `table1[3]` is `System.String` and `table2[3]` is `System.Boolean`. So the cast is failing on `table2.Field<string>(3)`.

So replace your `where` with the appropriate test:

```
where (table1.Field<string>(3) == "1") == table2.Field<bool>(3)
```

Comment: Reason I'm using a string is because the value in the Datatable is not a bool value, but more of an int; however, some of the where clauses I will add will have either a value of 0, 1, A, B. So I was hoping I could use a <string>

Comment: I think you need to find out the type of `dt1.Rows[0][3]` - the `Field` must match.

Comment: I receive a "Specified cast is not valid." when using `table1.Field<bool>(3) == table2.Field<bool>(3)`

Comment: Thought that I would take out the one Where clause and add `select table1[3].GetType()` at the end. It even comes back as a System.String. So I'm lost

Comment: @54696d I changed my answer to modify the join to see if you get a different message.

Comment: Error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Boolean' to type 'System.String'." Plus you had a extra ) at the end }. I appreciate your response.

Comment: What does `select table2[3].GetType()` yield?

Comment: I posted that above. It's a System.String

Comment: That was for `table1`. I did not want to assume `table2` is the same.

Comment: Sorry, long day of fixing other issues. Actually I'm showing it is a System.Boolean. Why can't it convert?

Comment: I changed my answer again :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up changing the Datatable's data types on some of the columns and changed the data from 1 to true and 0 to false when creating the DT. Either way works